# Fill remaining space after image resize keeping its aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 2 div’s one containing an image(400x600) that will be sized to the div keeping its aspect ratio. The other panel should fill the remaining space. When the viewport resizes, the image resizes as expected but the flex does not fill the remaining space. How can I change the flexbox to fill the remaining space? This gif shows the problem:

[image]

This is what I got to but I just can't figure out how to get the bigger div to fillup when the image scales down. Basically, I need panel-2 to fill the void that is created when the image scales down. So that there is no space between the 2 panels.

```css
body {
  background-color: #afafaf;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.img-scaleing {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.panel1 {
  background-color: #b7d1d4;
}

.panel2 {
  flex: 100%;
  background-color: #a493c3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x600/d4b9d4/7477a3.png" class="img-scaleing" />
  </div>
  <div class="panel2"></div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oRmJZx

Comment: the ratio will always be the same? (400x600)

Comment: What does *"but the flex doesn't fill the remaining space"* mean, exactly?

Comment: @TemaniAfif nope unfortunately the image can be any size.

Comment: I mean the div=>panel2 with flex:100% does not fill the remaining space after the image scaled down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using vh and not setting the height of the HTML document

```
 html{
  height:100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #afafaf;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.img-scaleing {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.panel1 {
  background-color: #b7d1d4;
  height:100%;
}

.panel2 {
  flex: 100%;
  background-color: #a493c3;
}
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use flex-grow

```css
body {
  background-color: #afafaf;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.img-scaleing {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.panel1 {
  background-color: #b7d1d4;
}

.panel2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #a493c3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container trimed-content">
  <div class="panel1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x600/d4b9d4/7477a3.png" class="img-scaleing" />
  </div>
  <div class="panel2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Write the .img-scaleing CSS with normal `height` and `width`. Set that to 100% so it takes up the whole `panel-1` (or whatever the container is).

```css
   body {
      background-color: #afafaf;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .container {
      background-color: #fff;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
    }
    .img-scaleing {
    width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .panel1 {
      background-color: #b7d1d4;
    }
    .panel2 {
      flex: 100%;
      background-color: #a493c3;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container trimed-content">
  <div class="panel1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x600/d4b9d4/7477a3.png" class="img-scaleing" />
  </div>
  <div class="panel2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it should keep the aspect ratio.